# How do I write an ActiveRecord scope that returns the most recently created 2 records that belong to their parent?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, activerecord-relation

For example, say I have an Author class and a Book class. How do I write a scope for **books** that are the most recently created records belonging to **their author**?

I know that a scope for the most recently created books is

`scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(4) }`

However, that returns the most recently created books by any author.

I'm looking for something like:

`author 1: Plato`

`id | title     | created_at
 1  |  Apology  | 23 Jul 2018 
 2  |  Phaedo   | 24 Jul 2018 
 3  |  Republic | 25 Jul 2018`

`author 2: Seneca`

`id | title     | created_at
 4  | Oedipus   | 3 May 2018 
 5  | Agamemnon | 4 May 2018 
 6  | Hercules  | 5 May 2018`

to return `Hercules, Agamemnon, Republic, and Phaedo`

Comment: You can query by the foreign_key, `scope :most_recent, ->(author_id) { where(author_id: author_id).order(created_at: :desc).limit(2) }`.

Answer (score 2):

ALl the above answers are not following the Rails conventions of single responsibility. Having the scope on the Book like you have is the only correct answer!

```
class Book
  scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(4) }
end
```

And query like this:

```
# for author with ID=3
Author.find(3).books.most_recent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in the `Book` class like this:

```
scope: most_recent_by_author, ->(author_id) { where(author_id: author_id).order(created_at: :desc).limit(2) }
```

To query:

`Book.most_recent_by_author(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :most_recent, lambda { |*args|joins(:author).where(books:{:author_id=>args}).order('books.created_on DESC').limit(2) }
```

Write the above scope in your Book Model.
To query for most recent books by any author call:

```
Book.most_recent(author_id)
```

author_id = Id of author/Author Model object for which you want the most recent books.

Comment: The `where` query method also accepts an array of ids, so the splat within the lambda isn't necessary. Also being Book the model, both "books" specification in where and order and superfluous.